# How to config nginx about proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I run `tomcat` and my `nginx.conf` like this
[image]

If in `http://127.0.0.1:8080/edu/b.html` or `http://192.168.0.102:8080/edu/b.html` it's ok

If in `http://192.168.0.102:9001/edu/b.html` it can't work

> my computer ip now is `192.168.0.102`

[image]

error message

```
[error] 17810#17810: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192    .168.0.102, server: 192.168.0.102, request: "GET /edu/b.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/edu/b.html", host: "192.    168.0.102:9001"
```

Where is error? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is trying to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/edu/b.html`(upstream) instead of `http://192.168.0.102:8080/edu/b.html`. You need to change the upstream port in your nginx.conf